# Delete or hide SSRS Shared Data Sources folder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I am restructuring my departments SSRS environment.  Under the new structure I want to keep our shared data sources listed in a folder directly under the solution instead of under the project.  Does anyone know how I can delete or hider the project Shared Data Sources folder in visual studio?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Reporting Services, A shared data source is a set of data source connection properties that can be referenced by multiple reports, models, and data-driven subscriptions that run on a Reporting Services report server.

It must be within one project. We can't specify one data source working for multiple projects. In this scenario, we suggest you put those reports into one project. Otherwise you can only create one data source for each project.